# Ruby on Rails button to change the date field in the database to the current date for all products in the shopping list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A user can have multiple lists and a list can have multiple products

A product has a name and a date of last purchase

I am trying to add a button for each shopping list which on click it should update the last_purchase date with the current date for all the specific products added to the list already

**This is what i have now**

index.html.erb(in the list view folder) {each list has this button}

`<%= button_to "Just-Shopped", just_shopped_product_path(...), :method => :put %>`

routes.rb

```
resources :products do
    member do
       put 'just_shopped'
    end
  end
```

I know i am meant to create a function in the controller of list, but I am not sure how to select all products from the list ignoring the not selected ones and then updating that last_purchased field with the current date

[This is a picture of how the rails console behaves when displaying products of a list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skWxc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track - first of all it looks like you want the button to apply to a list's products rather than an individual product, so let's change the route to:

```
resources :lists do
  member do
     put 'just_shopped'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in our lists_controller:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
   ...


  def just shopped
    list = List.find(params[:id])
    list.products.each do |product|
      product.update_attributes(last_purchased: DateTime.now)
    end
  end
```

That's our route and controller action setup, now we just need to add the correct button. I'm assuming you've got a @lists variable (or current_user.lists or something like that), and you're iterating through them as such:

```
<% @lists.each do |list| %>
  <%# whatever html you want for each list %>
  <%= button_to "Just-Shopped", just_shopped_list_path(list), :method => :put %>
end
```

You'll also need to figure out where you want to redirect to after you've updated the products in your controller